# Using created filter to filter specific value base on other cells value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I can't seem to figure this out. I am wonder if it is possible to create a filter for a column, and then filter that column based on another cells value. So I have created a filter for A column which contains values of TEST1,TEST2. I then have a dropdown in C1 that have the values of First, Second.

Here is the formula I put on costume formula. It does not return any value. Also, I am not new to coding, so I don't know if this is right.

=IF(C1="First",A2:A="TEST1",IF(C1="Second",A2:A="TEST2"",""))

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Please include a sample of your data as well as another example of your expected results. I've provided [an answer below](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172718/) based on a "best guess"

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uCCiR6wteqjSAIULN_t7VMhE2mAFDLyBWfeq4sQB1lM/edit?usp=sharing

The formula you provided will work for filtering in a new array. What I am wondering is if it is possible to use the created filter and a costume formula in it to sort a specific value if a value in another cell is true (First, Second).

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

```
=IFNA(
   FILTER(
     A2:A, A2:A=
       HLOOKUP(
         C1,{"First", "Second";
             "TEST1", "TEST2"}, 2, 0)))
```

The same formula as a single line:

```
=IFNA(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A=HLOOKUP(C1,{"First","Second";"TEST1","TEST2"},2,0)))
```

## Explanation

1. [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) `A2:A` for values that match the result of a [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en).
2. The [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en) returns the value in the second row of the same column whose first row matches `C1`.
3. [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en) returns a blank value instead of an error if `C1` doesn't match a value in the [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en) or if the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) result is empty.